# MySQL Cluster Replication: Multi-Master with Geographically distributed locations

Tags: mysql

I read about MySQL Cluster Replication: Multi-Master but one thing that is not clear to me is how good MySQL scales when the Clusters are spread across different geographical locations.

By this I mean that nodes with the cluster are connected with High Bandwidth network but clusters communicate through a low bandwidth network. Is still a good idea to use Multi-Master replication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are different modes for configuring MySQL Cluster across geographic locations - either asynchronously or synchronously

Both are discussed at the blog below, but are right that you do need to consider additional factors when distributing across locations, ie to maintain the same overall throughput, higher client concurrency would be required

There is more information here:
http://blogs.oracle.com/MySQL/entry/synchronously_replicating_databases_across_data